# No puedo validar formulario con semantic ui y ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nodejs, semantic-ui

Quiero verificar si un valor ingresado en el input `#rol_nombre` no se encuentra en la base de datos para poder almacenarlo.

`input`

```
<div class="field">
   <div class="ui corner labeled input">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre." name="rol_nombre" id="rol_nombre">;
   <div class="ui corner label">
   <i class="asterisk icon"></i>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

`backend`

Cuando encuentra un registro con el mismo nombre retorna `false`.

```
findByName: async (req, res) => {
        let rows = await Rol.findByName(req.query.key);
        if (rows.length > 0) {
            res.send(false);
        } else {
            res.send(true);
        }
    }
```

`script del formulario`

```js
$(() => {
        $.fn.form.settings.rules.myCustomRule = function (param) {
            $.ajax({
                url: `/rol/search?key=${param}`,
                success: function (respuesta) {
                    console.log(respuesta);
                    return respuesta;
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("No se ha podido obtener la información");
                }
            });
        }
        $('#frm-rol').form({

            rol_nombre: {
                identifier: 'rol_nombre',
                rules: [
                    { type: 'empty', prompt: 'Ingrese un nombre' },
                    { type: 'maxLength[45]', prompt: 'Debe ingresar maximo 10 caracteres' },
                    { type: 'myCustomRule[nombre]', prompt: 'El nombre ya fue registrado' }
                ]
            }

        })
    });
```

El problema parece ser durante el retorno de la respuesta en la función `myCustomRule`, se supone que si recibe el `true` de mi petición ajax debería continuar con el registro, pero no lo hace, el `console.log(respuesta)` ejecutado en el `success` imprime correctamente la respuesta que recibe del `backend` pero a mi criterio `myCustomRule` no recibe el `true` del ajax.

Comment: O algún lugar donde pueda obtener información al respecto ?

Comment: y si en vez de enviar el `true` como boleano desde el backend lo envias como string `"true"` y una compracion sencilla como `if(response == "true")//...`

Comment: dentro de `$.fn.form.settings.rules.myCustomRule = function (param) {   }` funciona si retorno directamente `true`, pero si ese `true` lo devuelvo dentro de una función, ya no vale.

Comment: Utiliza la funciones de flecha, `$.fn.form.settings.rules.myCustomRule = param=> { }`

Comment: añadí mas información a la publicación. eso de la función flecha no resulto.

Comment: Tu problema es de sincronía. En la [documentación](https://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html#adding-custom-rules) de Semantic-UI, especifica claramente que: (traducción propia) _Puedes extender la validación del formulario para incluir tus propias reglas. Ten en cuenta que esto necesariamente se debe realizar de forma **sincrónica**._ Con esto ya tienes una idea de lo que está sucediendo. Las llamadas AJAX son asíncronas. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

La cuestión es que `myCustomRule` es de quien se espera la respuesta `true` o `false` para dar por válida la regla.

Pero `myCustomRule`, al llamar a `$.get` invoca una operación asincrónica, por lo tanto una vez que llamó a `$.get`, la función sigue adelante y termina.

La respuesta al `$.get` se procesa con la función pasada como lambda y se ejecuta más adelante cuando se reciben los datos de la respuesta, pero para este momento ya la validación de `myCustomRule` terminó.

Alternativas que se pueden evaluar:

En lugar de `$.get` usar `$.ajax` con `async:false`. En el callback de `success` setear una variable del contexto de `myCustomRule` y luego evaluar ese resultado:

```
$.fn.form.settings.rules.myCustomRule = function (param) {  
    let rol_state = -1;
    $.ajax({
        url : `/rol/search?key=${param}`,
        type : "get",
        async: false,
        success : function(data) {
            rol_state = data.rol_state;
        },
        error: function() {
           connectionError();
        }
    });

    if (rol_state == -1) {
       console.log('Error no contemplado');
       return false;
    }else if (rol_state == 1) {
       console.log('Registrado y activo');
       return false;
    } else if (rol_state == 0) {
       console.log('Registrado pero esta inactivo');
       return false;
    } else {
       console.log('No existe coincidencias');
       return true;
    }

}
```

Hacer que la llamada sea sincrónica puede trer otros problemas (Por este motivo, si bien la opción existe, está deprecada) por lo que me inclinaría mas por otra solución.  Por ejemplo:

I. En lugar de usar un botón de submit en el formulario, utilizar un botón que se encargue de hacer la llamada de `ajax` (asincrónica).
Y luego, en el callback de `success`, de esa llamada, si el nombre no existe, hacer el submit del formulario por programa.

o II. Quitar la validación de `myCustomRule` e implementarla aparte como una precondición para poder habilitar el botón de submit del formulario:

Cuando se ingresa el nombre, esperar a que se termine de escribir, y ejecutar el `$.get()`.
En el callback de success, mostrar el error si ya existe el nombre, o habilitar el botón de submit del formulario si se verificó que el nombre no existe.

Comment: Estimado gracias por la respuesta, ingreso un valor que ya existe en la base de datos y  en la consola obtengo el mensaje (Registrado y activo) por lo tanto no debería registrarse la información, pero lo hace.

Comment: Si sale ese log en la consola, la función está devolviendo false como debería. Fijate si en la consola sale algún otro error.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que myCustomRule devuelve `undefined`, ya que no haces ningún return.

Para poder manejar $.ajax, de forma sincrónica y poder usarlo como validador, podés usar Async/Await:

```
$.fn.form.settings.rules.myCustomRule = async param => {
  let isValid;
  try {
    isValid = await $.ajax({
      url: `/rol/search?key=${param}`
    });
  } catch (err) {
    isValid = false;
  }

  return isValid;
};
```

Comment: amigo gracias, pero aun así el formulario se sigue enviando y no sucede nada